# Is $P(\frac{X}{Y}<a)$ greater when $Cov(X,Y)>0$ than when $Cov(X,Y)=0$ if $X$ and $Y$ are positive random variables?

Tags: probability, covariance

As the question says, is $P(\frac{X}{Y}<a)$ greater when X and Y have positive covariance than when they are independent (both positive random variables)? 
 
My intuition is that if Y is likely to be larger when X is larger, then X/Y is likely to be smaller than if X and Y were independent. 
 
Specifically I'm interested in the case X and Y are non central chi squared distributions. 
 
I'm not sure how to prove or disprove this though.

Comment: Are you perhaps assuming $X$ and $Y$ are *positive* random variables??  Even then, looking at a plot of the potential support of $(X,Y)$ along with the line $X=aY$ ought to improve your intuition.

Comment: Ah yes forgot to mention they are positive. How could I plot X, Y if I don't know what distribution they are?

Comment: Your question isn't really about specific distributions: it is *solely* about how the probability is split between the wedge above the line $X=aY$ and the wedge below the line $X=aY$ in the first quadrant.  If you know how to visualize correlations and covariances, the answer IMHO will come to you immediately.

Comment: If I'm understanding this certainly agrees with my intuition, but I'm looking for a proof as well and not sure how to do that.

Comment: A "proof" is irrelevant: you need a *counterexample.*  They're easy to come by using the method I have suggested.

Comment: Perhaps for you, I'm not sure how to do so

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample: consider the case of perfect correlation, where $X = Y$, so $X / Y = 1$.  Now consider the case of i.i.d. $X$ and $Y$, where $p(x = 1) = p(x = 2) = 1/2$, and of course the same for $Y$.  The probability that $X/Y < 1$ in the former case is zero, but in the latter case, is $1/4$.

Comment: Yeah I see. Is there an example of two random variables that have continuous and non zero pdfs everywhere $\geq 0$?

Comment: Sure, you could do the same thing with any such distribution.  The key is that with a correlation of $1$, under the setup above, $X$ cannot be less than $Y$, therefore $X/Y$ cannot be less than 1.  With continuous i.i.d. variates, $p(x < y) = 1/2$ by symmetry, therefore $p(x/y < 1) = 1/2$, which is obviously $>0$.